# Perl replace a string which is in a line above matching pattern

Tags: regex, perl

If there is a string (e.g. "TODAY,TOMORROW,YESTERDAY") in any line for all the *.java files in a directory(and its sub directories), then replace a string  in the line above (eg., "Raining,Cloudy,Windy"  to "Sunny") and print them to a csv file before replacing (eg., file1.java TODAY Raining, File2.java TOMMOROW Cloudy)
But my regex is not working as desired. Also, is there any other better way to achieve the mentioned requirement?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my @day = ("TODAY", "TOMORROW", "YESTERDAY");
my @weather = ("Raining", "Cloudy", "Windy");

my $dayregex = join "|", @day; 
$dayregex    = qr/\b($dayregex)\b/; 

my $weatherregex = join "|", @weather; 
$weatherregex    = qr/\b($weatherregex)\b/;

my $output = 'output.csv'; 

#Getting list of files in dir and sub dirs
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.java' )
                        ->in( 'C:/Users/path/to/folder/' );

for my $file (@files) {
print "Opening file: $file\n";
open(INPUT, $file) or die("Input file $file not found. \n");

while (my $line = <INPUT>) {
  if ($line =~ m/$dayregex/ {
    print "There was a match on $1 from array day\n";

    #send the output to csv before replacing
    open(OUTPUT, '>'.$output) or die("Cannot create $output file. \n");
    print OUTPUT $file $1 $weatherregex; 
    close(OUTPUT);

    #Replace the matched weatherregex string with Sunny
    $line =~ s/$weatherregex(.*\n.*$1)/Sunny/g ;
   }
 }
}
close(INPUT);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`weatherregex(.*\n)+`

I think this will work to find weatherregex is presented in multiple line or splitted into two lines.